# Function return subtype of a generic marker interface

Tags: typescript

I have a marker interface like this:

```
interface IRequest<TResponse> {
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to write a function with 2 parameters of the same `IRequest<TResponse>` type and returns the `TResponse` type of those parameters?

I've done something like this but when I call this function the return type is `unknown` instead of `TResponse`.

```
interface IRequest<T> {
  name: string;
}

class FooResponse {
}

class Foo implements IRequest<FooResponse> {
  name = 'foo';
  key1?: string;
  key2?: string;
}

function getResponse<T extends IRequest<U>, U>(t: new() => T, args: Partial<T>): U {
    const obj = new t();
    Object.assign(obj, args);
  console.log(obj);

  // some API call treatment using variable obj which returns type U
  return {} as U;
}

const value = getResponse(Foo, { key1: 'bar' }); // value is unknown instead of FooResponse
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJICUIEcCuEDOYAPACoB8yA3gFDLIhwC2EAXMoVKAOYDc1AvtWoIANnHz5kAMQD2MzPgAOMkPhQ1BwsROlzkwRopERm4SRmx5CRWfILLVECjToNmyALzIA5DDne%20OgBrCABPAEYAfjYObkDkENCAJmj2ME4QXgEhGBwQBDBgFWQuCDAFBzVSZAgAD0gQABNzTFwCYgBVMgAaZC6ACjA2EAgAd36ASk8KEl64KC58NgAFecK4EVIyCbYOqmoASAQVQmQZACMAK096MeQwSb4DgHkriAKAOnF8YC4QfoulzmC3wE3ix1UMmMHxEMi4AKuYKEdAA9Cj2DJ3ABBZaoZAIDYie5QCBwMCmMDIHA-TLIABu82AcHOxjOV2QowAFsAEJzkCSwDgoKp7qFFCgOrR%20WUhSAqPxkOI%20nxNBDTgyRHgbqVyvYThB%20rZepQEmFwmxvOd5t5kPwwcg0fSNlrgJI8kEQDJRnLQIRSY0zjBdHYlPrqEA)

Comment: Please [edit] this code to be a [mre] that we can copy and paste into our own IDEs to see what you're seeing without unrelated problems you're not asking about.  It shouldn't have pseudocode (e.g., `...`) or unused generics (e.g., `TResponse` inside the `IRequest` interface) or undeclared types (e.g., `FooResponse`). Providing a [mre] will make it a lot easier for us to get started helping you.  Presumably you're getting `unknown` because there is no place from which to infer `TResponse` in `getResponse()` (constraints are not inference sites) but I can't be sure without a [mre].

Comment: You seem to be overcomplicating things - https://tsplay.dev/Nrj0DN infers `FooResponse` just fine, for example.

Comment: I've done a tsplayground to reproduce : tsplay.dev/N9YLjN
@jonrsharpe > In your example "args" is not of type T, i want to make sure the same type is used

Comment: Please [edit] to put the code in the question itself as plaintext; a link in the comments to an external IDE doesn't suffice (although a link is nice, we need to code to live here for it to be a [mre]).  I note that you are still not using your generic parameter `T` inside `IRequest<T>`.  That is [not recommended and causes weird behavior](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-type-inference-work-on-this-interface-interface-foot--).  Unless you're trying to ask about *that*, please add a structural dependence on `T`.

Comment: Reiterating because recent edits don't seem to reflect it: TS doesn't have "marker interfaces".  If you have a type `interface IRequest<T> { name: string; }` then `IRequest<string>` and `IRequest<number>` and `IRequest<FooResponse>` are all identical to each other.  If you want to be able to infer `T` form `IRequest<T>` reliably, please give it a structural dependency like, for example, `interface IRequest<T> {name: string, r(): Promise<T>}` or something.  [Please read this FAQ entry](//github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-type-inference-work-on-this-interface-interface-foot--).

Comment: Thank you for the FAQ entry, I mixed things up with C# generics. I will rethink a way to do this without my marker interface

Comment: I see you already accepted another answer; you can still use an interface but it should depend on its parameter.. if you do that, then you can still have the same problem with your `getResponse()` function to start with but now it's fixable like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WPMqKw). I'd be happy to write that up as an answer but I'm not sure how to proceed now.  Oh well!

Comment: @jcalz **infer** keyword is exactly what I want, thank you  !!

Comment: Great, and I'd write up an answer, but you've already accepted another answer.  How should I proceed?

Comment: I removed the accepted answer, you can write yours

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, there really isn't such a thing in TypeScript as a "marker interface".  If you want `IRequest<T>` to depend on `T` in a way that can be used for inference, then you need to make `IRequest<T>` depend on `T` *[structurally](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system)*.  It needs to have a property where `T` appears.  Otherwise `IRequest<X>` is structurally identical to `IRequest<Y>` no matter what `X` and `Y` are, and therefore TypeScript considers them the same type… and therefore there is nowhere from which you could reliably infer the type argument. See [the relevant FAQ entry](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-type-inference-work-on-this-interface-interface-foot--) for more information.

So let's give `IRequest<T>` a member of type `T`:

```
interface IRequest<T> {
  name: string;
  x: T;
}
```

You can change that to something else if you want (e.g., `y: () => T`, `z(v: T) => T`, etc) but that's the minimal viable approach to proceed.

---

Anyway, the major problem with your `getResponse()` is that there is no *inference site* for the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook2/generics.html) type parameter `U`.  No parameter of `getResponse()` depends directly on `U`.  And `T` is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `IRequest<U>`, but TypeScript cannot use constraints as inference sites; this was suggested in [microsoft/TypeScript#7234](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7234) but it was never implemented.

You don't really want the function to be generic in `U` anyway; the type of `U` should be determined completely by `T`.  What you really want is to *compute* `U` from `T`.  To do so, you could use [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) via the `infer` keyword.  If you have a type like `type X = F<T>` then you can recover `T` from `X` like `X extends F<infer U> ? U : never`.

That gives us this:

```
function getResponse<T extends IRequest<any>>(
  t: new () => T, args: Partial<T>
): T extends IRequest<infer U> ? U : never {
  const obj = new t();
  Object.assign(obj, args);
  console.log(obj);
  return {} as any; // this isn't likely to be U anyway so just assert
}
```

Let's test it:

```
const value = getResponse(Foo, { key1: 'bar' });
// function getResponse<Foo>(t: new () => Foo, args: Partial<Foo>): FooResponse
// const value: FooResponse
```

Looks good.  TypeScript infers `Foo` for `T`, and then the return type is `FooResponse`, since `Foo` implements `IRequest<FooResponse>`.  And again, this only works because `IRequest<T>` depends structurally on `T`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJICUIEcCuEDOYAPACoB8yA3gFDLIhwC2EAXMoVKAOYDctyADzYk+AX2rUEAGzj58yAGIB7JZnwAHJSHwoadOMgC8yAIxiJ02fOVLkwRuqkRm4eRmx5CRG2s3aIFHr0TCjGAOQwKmF8dEKKKr5aOkb0EADu8aoEfjoAFACU-ADWEACeJgD8bBzcMcglpQBMVexgnCC81OIS1DA4IAhgwFrIXBBgif6kyBACkCAAJm6YuATEcCClZGS5YGwg6cgFRhQkADTIcFBc+GwACldDcFKkZPks-CQzcxCLyx5rIigGDQZAAVQoFXByH2EAAbqCgggkmBkEoAEYAKxSBwyYAKdQA8liIIMAHRWYBcEC5DGYi5XG75OrI7RKJxkqRKLi0rHM-hQcY4KAgKiiS7yDalcySFHIOHPPApMYTbJJCC5GwXSj1MomNhhdFXMLIUT8gD05uQfQGQxGKsmOm8Kh2e1SGWOhgoWsu11uyAeUCeLxsbzYPjV-moluQrMI8sVrEyjogPSAA)

Answer (score 1):

If you check the code, without specifying the second generic parameter, it will be `unknown`.

This is what the intellisense says:

```
function getResponse<unknown, Foo>(t: new () => Foo, args: Partial<Foo>): unknown
```

A possible solution (what would fix your issue) would be to add the generic parameters:

```
const value = getResponse<FooResponse, Foo>(Foo, { key1: 'bar' });
```

This changes are needed, because you specified `U` as a generic parameter, in the method, but you didnt populate it when actually calling the function.

If you dont want to add the generic property, you can do it heuristically, what could work, but personally i dont like it:

```
const value: FooResponse = getResponse(Foo, { key1: 'bar' });
```

But in these two cases you have to change your code everywhere.